# Web-API Versioning not working with Default version

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, api-versioning

I created one web API application with versioning. I am going to use `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning` package to do that.

Webapi configuration:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.AddApiVersioning(o => {
            o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        });
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    }
}
```

Here my assumption is if I didn't pass the version, by default it will select version 1.

Controller code:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UserV1Controller : BaseController
{
    public UserV1Controller()
    {
    }

    [Route("all", Name = "UsersCollection")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var items = await UnitOfWork.Users.GetPaged(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Id), 1, 20);
        //Add mapping to DTO 
        return Ok(items);
    }

}
```

If I test with `http://localhost:10280/api/users/all?api-version=1.0` URL, it working fine. I am going to implement this feature in the existing project.

For backward compatibility, I tried `http://localhost:10280/api/users/all` URL.
It gives me the following error with **500** as the status code.

> {
>   "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "The index cannot be less than 0 or equal to or larger than the number of items in the collection.\r\n
> Parameter
>   name: index\r\nActual value was 0.",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException",
>       "StackTrace": "   at 
> System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HostedHttpRouteCollection.get_Item(Int32
>   index)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Http.Dispatcher.ApiVersionControllerSelector.GetControllerName(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Http.Dispatcher.ControllerSelectionContext.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<.ctor>b__0()\r\n
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n   at
>   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Http.Dispatcher.ConventionRouteControllerSelector.SelectController(ControllerSelectionContext
>   context)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Http.Dispatcher.ApiVersionControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"
>   }

---

**Update 1:**

After discussions and a bit of help, I can confirm that this default version works with conventional routing.

The issue reproduced while using attribute routing. Please check my updated code.

1. I don't have any default API routing in the WebAPIConfig file.
2. I update Route Prefix and Route in the controller

Now the issue reproduced.

You can also reproduce the issue with combining conventional and attribute.

## Update 2:

Now I noticed that the issue lies in the configuration. If I add the routing configurations in the Owin startup class directly it working fine.

```
    public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        var configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();
        var httpServer = new System.Web.Http.HttpServer(configuration);

        // reporting api versions will return the headers "api-supported-versions" and "api-deprecated-versions"
        configuration.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        });
        configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        app.UseWebApi(httpServer);

    }
}
```

It creates new ***HttpConfiugration*** other than using our existing WebAPIConfig class. So I don't know it may impact any other functionalities

So if i configure Owin to use webaPI instead of ***GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)*** in the Global.asax, it iw working fine.

Comment: This is the route config for mvc. We need the route config for your webapi. this is most likely located in the WebApiConfig.cs if not changed

Comment: ok. So only I confused. Actually, I removed that default route lines as I configured only for attribute routing. I updated now. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Na. It's ok. Your route config seems ok. I can now safely reproduce your error. Now let's just find a solution for it

Comment: ok, thanks. I tried all the ways specified. If not got anything seems like go ahead by extending ControllerSelector

Comment: Is there a controller using version 2, that has the same routeprefix? e.g. `[RoutePrefix("api/users")]`? because this is causing your error in my local project. If I delete the second controller or its routeprefix, the error goes away.
This is only natural, since there cannot be 2 identical routes for 2 different controllers.

Comment: Ok I understood. But here I created only one controller as a sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186037/discussion-between-akhil-and-marco).

Comment: I reproduced the behavior. Using conventional routing it is working fine. If I used Attribute routing, reproduced the issue with single controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug that only occurs when hosting on a vanilla IIS implementation (e.g. non-OWIN). Despite the **HttpRouteCollection** having an indexer, the **HostedHttpRouteCollection** defined by System.Web does not support it. Instead of throwing **NotSupportedException**, a generic **ArgumentOutOfRangeException** is thrown.

For more details see: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/428.

The fix is in and is now available in package version [3.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning/3.0.1).

Comment: Thanks. Working as expected in version 3.0.1

Answer (score 3):

If you do not specify a version it is considered unversioned. In this case you have to set the `AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified` property, which if not told otherwise, assumes a default version of `"1.0"`, if none is specified:

```
config.AddApiVersioning(o => {
    o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
});
```

This functionality is documented here: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Existing-Services-Quick-Start

Comment: no. I can access if i provide the api version explicitly. I also tried the same sample specified in the documentation but same error. Any other configuration?

Comment: my fault, please edit your question with your route config. I can recreate your error by adding the `[Route]` decorator on an action method.

Comment: Your route config is still missing from your question

Comment: I added the route.config file code. As this is API only I think we don't care about route.config. correct? I just care only in webApiConfig file

Comment: Now I updated with my latest findings. But I don't know why it happened like that

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up the default version number and configure middleware to use it when version number is not specified.

Reference: [Scott's blog on routing](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETCoreRESTfulWebAPIVersioningMadeEasy.aspx)

```
services.AddApiVersioning(
    o =>
    {
        o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true );
        o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion("1.0");
    } );
```

Comment: That won't work, since his routes do not use DateTimes as version attributes. A suitable overload would have been `new ApiVersion(1,0)`

Comment: thanks. but that is not the issue. I think this is related to routing. This issue reproduced when I use RoutePrefix and Route attributes only. I mean Attribute routing